# Counting Syllables, loop issue

Tags: java, string, loops

I am trying to count syllables and right now I'm running some test to see if I can find vowels and then go from there. However, my output is coming up as 0 and I fail to see where the error is.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Word{

    private char[] letters;
    private char[] vowels;
    private int ct;
    private int temp;
    private int syllableCt;
    private int iftest;

    public Word(String[] words){
        temp = 0;
        ct = 0;
        for (int i = 0;i<words.length;i++){

            temp = countSyllables(words[i]);

        }

    }

    public int countSyllables(String str){

        char[] letters = str.toCharArray();
        syllableCt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<letters.length;i++){
            if (isVowel(letters[i]))
                syllableCt++;




            System.out.println("" + letters[i] + "\n");
            System.out.println("" + syllableCt + "\n");



        }
        return syllableCt;
    }
    public boolean isVowel(char ch){

        int iftest = 0;
        char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y','A','E','I','O','U','Y'};
        for (int i = 0;i<vowels.length;i++){
            if (ch == i)
                iftest = 1;

        }
        if (iftest == 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String[] words;
        words = new String[5];
        words[0] = "dog";
        words[1] = "moon";
        words[2] = "syllables";
        words[3] = "reddit";
        words[4] = "3749832";
        Word word = new Word(words);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you repost the code as code formatting instead of quote formatting?

Comment: @Scorpion "Y" can be both vowel and consonant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There looks to be a mistake in the method which checks for the vowel

```
if (ch == i)
          iftest = 1;
```

The check should be ch== vowels [i]. Also, the method and class can be greatly refactored, can't help there as I don 't have access to a computer right now.

See if the method below works :

```
public boolean isVowel(char ch){

  int iftest = 0;
  char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y','A','E','I','O','U','Y'};
  for (int i = 0;i<vowels.length;i++){
      if (ch == vowels[i])
          return true;

  }
  
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Im glad you also changed the function to return immediately instead of using those check variables.  That bothered me, have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

instead of
    if(ch == i)

you want

```
if(ch == vowels[i])
```

in your isVowel() method

Answer (score 0):

Look at the assignment to 'temp' in your loop. If you want to calculate the total number of syllables in all words, you want to accumulate the number into temp like so: temp += countSyllables... If you want a separate count per word, you want temp to be an array, and fill that out inside your loop.

Right now you're only seeing the last syllable count, which is correct given that the last word does not have vowels.

Answer (score 0):

In `isVowel`, you're comparing the letter to `i`. You should be comparing it to `vowels[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

the line:

```
if (ch == i)
```

compares the character against the loop index, you prpbably meant:

```
if (ch == vowels[i])
```

instead of managing a flag named `iftest` you can return true when you find a vowel directly, as in (pseudo code):

```
loop over vowels {
    if character == vowel
        return true
}
return false
```

plus you probably don't want to reset `syllableCt` to `0` every call to `countSyllables()`.